# return data from php dropdownlist after submit

Tags: php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

hey guys i've passed way more time on this then what i originally wanted to...

so i have this code here, where i have a drop list give me data from a sql database from the selection of 3 radio buttons, that all works fine.

My problem come when i want to submit my form and get info of the data in said droplist. all i want is put the selected radio and the selected item in the single drop list in variables in the submission.php that comes after the post method of the form...

anyway thats what i want to do for now

```
<?php

require "../Scripts/config.php"; // database connection here
?>

<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 3.2//en">

<html>

<head>
<title>test</title>

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
function reload()
{

for(var i=0; i < document.form1.type.length; i++){
if(document.form1.type[i].checked)
var val=document.form1.type[i].value 
}

self.location='bob.php?type=' + val ;

}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?Php


$tp=$_GET['type']; // getting the value from query string
if(strlen($tp) > 1){$sql="SELECT * FROM Subcategory where cat_id='$tp'";}
echo $sql;


echo "<form name=form1 id=form1 method=post action=submissions2.php>"; 
echo "<select name=Subcategory id=Subcategory value=''>Subcategory</option>"; // printing the list box select command
foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row){//Array or records stored in $row
echo "<option value=$row[cat_id]>$row[Subcategory]</option>"; 
/* Option values are added by looping through the array */ 
} echo "</select>";// Closing of list box

echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

echo "
<b>Type</b>
<input type=radio name=type value='1_Cosplay' onclick=\"reload()\";>Cosplay
<input type=radio name=type value='1_Modeling' onclick=\"reload()\";>Modeling
<input type=radio name=type value='1_Zombie' onclick=\"reload()\";>Zombie
<input type=submit value=Submit> </form>";



echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
?>


</body>

</html>
```

and this is the submissions2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
function filter($data) {
/*$data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);*/
return $data;
return $row;
}
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
$mydata[$key] = filter($value);
}

echo $mydata['Subcategory'];
echo "<br>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

all i seem to be able to get is the radio button choice.

Comment: You probably want to use AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an all-in-one solution. You need to change some references like what the name/local path of the file path is, but anyway, this contains all the code. I can not test the DB stuff but the ajax works if you have the correct url path in the jQuery portion. Note, this solution references itself, not a new page:

```
        // Display errors for troubleshooting
        ini_set('display_errors','1');
        error_reporting(E_ALL);

        class CategorySelector
            {
                public  function LoadSubCat()
                    {
                        // You will be subjected to an injection hack if you don't filter or encode this variable
                        // You should do PDO with prepared statements
                        $parent_cat =   htmlspecialchars($_GET['parent_cat'], ENT_QUOTES);
                        $query      =   $this->Fetch("SELECT id,subcategory_name FROM subcategories WHERE categoryID = '$parent_cat'");

                        // Uncomment this to see how this returns
                        // $this->PrintPre($query);  ?>

                        <label for="sub_cat">Sub Category</label>
                        <select name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat">
                        <?php
                        if($query !== 0) {
                                foreach($query as $row) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['subcategory_name']; ?></option>
                            <?php
                                    }
                            } ?>

                        </select>

                        <?php
                    }

                public function Form()
                    {
                        // Get rows for categories
                        $results    =   $this->Fetch("SELECT id,category_name FROM categories");

                        // Uncomment this to see how this returns
                        // $this->PrintPre($results); ?>

                    <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post">
                        <label for="parent_cat">Parent Category</label>
                        <select name="parent_cat" id="parent_cat">
                            <?php 
                            if($results !== 0) {
                                foreach($results as $row) { ?>

                            <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['category_name']; ?></option>
                            <?php   }
                            } ?>
                        </select>

                        <!-- This is a container that will load in your next menu -->
                        <div id="sub_cat_container"></div>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /> 
                    </form>     
                    <?php
                    }

                public  $rowCount;

                // This is strictly a returning engine for SQL statements
                protected   function Fetch($_sql)
                    {
                        include_once('config.php');
                        // You really should do prepared statements (PDO)
                        // This way of calling sql is depricated
                        $query          =   mysql_query($_sql);
                        // Save the row count
                        $this->rowCount =   mysql_num_rows($query);
                        // If there are rows return them
                        if($this->rowCount > 0) {
                                $_array =   array();
                                // Loop through
                                while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                                        $_array[]   =   $result;
                                    }
                            }
                        // Send back your query results for processing
                        // If no results, return false/0
                        return  (isset($_array))? $_array:0;
                    }

                protected function PrintPre($_array)
                    { ?>
                        <pre>
                        <?php print_r($_array); ?>
                        </pre>
                        <?php
                    }
            }

    // Uncomment this for testing that the AJAX is working.
    //   print_r($_REQUEST);

    // This is probably not the best way to do this all, but for sake
    // of trying to get it all to work, this whole thing will ajax to
    // itself, but if you can get it to work on this one page, you
    // can split it up into two pages.

    // Ok, so this creates a new instance of this whole system
    $builder    =   new CategorySelector();

    // If this page receives a GET request for $_GET['parent_cat'], just process it.
    // That action is to call the sub_cat dropdown menu from this object
    if(isset($_REQUEST['parent_cat']) && !empty($_REQUEST['parent_cat'])) {
            $builder->LoadSubCat();
        }
    // If there is no request, display the html page
    else {
    // You should not have space before the <!doctype>. Some browsers act funky if there is space before
    ?><!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dependent DropDown List</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // I'm not a javascript person, so this portion is kind of sloppy

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#parent_cat').change(function() {

            // Get value
            var ElmVal = $('#parent_cat').val();

            $.ajax({
                    // You need to reference this page in the "thispage.php" whatever this page is called
                    url:"/thispage.php?parent_cat="+ElmVal,
                    success:function(result) {
                        $("#sub_cat_container").html(result);
                }});
              });
            });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php 
        // Display the form.
        $builder->Form(); ?>

    </body>
    </html>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quote all your HTML attributes like `name='Subcategory'`, and

```
echo "<option value=$row[cat_id]>$row[Subcategory]</option>"
```

should be

```
echo "<option value='{$row['cat_id']}'>{$row['Subcategory']}</option>";
```

Your coding practice is horrible, by the way. You are not testing to see how many rows you have in your MySQL query, and you don't need to `echo` on each line. You can do this:

```
echo '<br />'.
'<br />';
```

Of course, using line breaks like that is a bad practice, as well. Use CSS.